# impossible to customize a WordPress theme

Tags: linux, wordpress, apache

I installed wordpress correctly but when I select a theme in order to modify it, I always come across the apache home page. which makes any modification impossible regardless of the theme.[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLaCe.png)

Answer (score 1):

Sometime I find that a hosting company, etc. has a "home" or "default" page which it prefers to show, instead of the WordPress index page. I would take a look at the root level for that index.html page and delete it. All the WordPress files/ pages are php pages, not html pages. I have had this exact problem and it can be a real heart-stopper when you know you installed WordPress correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your web server could not get route of wordpress application

In some scenarios .htaccess file has wrong config or your apache vhost config file has some issues

Check your /etc/httpd/httpd.conf and your custom vhost config files

After that check your .htaccess files for correct configuration